# Native iOS component in Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

If we create a native iOS component using a native iOS library. Can we use that component in xamarin.iOS app development.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/

Comment: I know that we can use iOS libraries in Xamarin.ios .My question is that whether we could use the native ios code written by us in Xamarin.ios

Comment: That link is how to bind 3rd-party ObjC libraries, if the "native iOS code written by us" is not in a static/Framework based library then the answer is no to being able to just include it along side C# code. You would need to create a static/Framework lib that you can then bind it via an Xamarin.iOS binding Library (or a ObjC library that you can p/invoke(DllImport), i.e. a C-style interface.

Comment: Got it,Thank you.